# Find the resultant force in a motion problem with a loop

Tags: forces, kinematics, energy-conservation, centripetal-force

In the approximate diagram, the block with mass $m$ starts without movement in the position $P$ in the top of a hill with height $5R$. After that, the block falls down through the hill, and reaches a loop until it arrives at the position $Q$ with a height of $R$. If the loop is a circle of radius $R$ and there is no friction, what is the value of the resultant force in the point $Q$?

**My try**

I tried to use the law of conservation of energy in the points $P$ and $Q$, with this i get the speed, but i don't know how to continue in this problem.

Any hints?

[image]

Comment: The resultant force would be the vector sum of centripetal force, and the force due to gravity

Comment: @Eagle the centripetal force is in function of the mass?

Comment: The centripetal force is $mv^2/R$. Find v by energy conservation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the net force will be the resultant of the normal force which is horizontal (equal to centripetal force) at A and obviously the weight(=mg)which acts vertically downwards.

Comment: So the sum of both gives the answer?

Comment: The  vector  sum, not simply adding as scalars! The vector sum of two perpendicular vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ has magnitude $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that as it's a slope we''ll divide mg into components .Mg sintheta will provide linear acceleration whereas mgcostheta will provide centripetal acceleration.
Multiply by mass and u get the force .The resultant force would be the vector sum of centripetal force, and the force due to gravity.(As said in comment )